# Blank After Installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in Windows 7 yesterday (I used wubi to install it). After the install is complete I choose 'reboot now' and after the restart, appear the words *"Completing installation blablabla"*. After counting (completing installation) is completed, my laptop screen become blank (black). Then I turn off the laptop by force. When turned off, looks at a glance ubuntu page on the screen. I tried to uninstall and reinstall the previous version (11.04, 10.10, 10.04) and it all ends the same. **Blank**. I want to install Ubuntu again, although the old version (previously, I was using 10.10). My Laptop **Acer Aspire 4736**. Please help me to solve this problem. Sorry for my English. Thank you.

> I just tried, after reboot and come out the words "Completing
>   installation" I press Esc. Exit the screen such as GRUB. I choose
>   "Safe mode screen" and complete the installation process. After the
>   automatic restart of Ubuntu and come out GRUB. After I selected, there
>   was an error with the words, *"**The system is running in low-graphic
>   mode. Your screen, graphics card, amd input device setting could not
>   be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.**"*

Comment: Hello, Swietenia Rofika. Can you log in to Low-Graphic Mode? Windows is still working, right?